# angular js partials won't stay where they are

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Hi I have 3 partials in my index.html

```
<!--header view-->
 <div id="header" ng-include="'partials/header.html'"></div>

<!--main page view-->
   <div ui-view class=""></div>



<!-- Loading the Footer -->
  <div id="oilFooter" ng-include="'partials/footer.html'"></div>
</html>
</body>
```

The header currently is overlapping the main view below.

It looks like this:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

This is the css for header.html

```
header {
position: absolute;
top:0px;
 margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom:10px;
width:100%;
height:85px;
z-index:300;
background-color:#000000;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; color:#c4c4c4; font-size:16.0px; line-height:1.19em;
```

css for html

```
/* general settings */
html {
 min-height:100%;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
   /* background-color:#1c1c1c;*/
    background-color:#cecece;


}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but it seems like a CSS issue. Add this

```css
{
  background: #000 !important;
  color: #0f0 !important;
  outline: solid #f00 1px !important;
}
```

and check if you've got any elements that are straying out of the boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the header positioning to relative from absolute.